# Carrying a value into another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_qrscanner);
        fragment = (BarcodeFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.sample);
```

Is it possible to carry the value that i get from (setScanResultHandler(this)) into another activity?

```
        fragment.setScanResultHandler(this);
```

Comment: To get the current reference in your fragment just use getActivity()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is like this

For sending data

```
 String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyName");
 Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
 intent.putExtra("keyName","value");
```

For receiving at ActivityTwo

```
String value= getIntent().getStringExtra("keyName");
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the Activity context in a fragment, No need to pass anything, Just use getActivity() in your fragment.

If you want to pass data like integer, strings, arrays etc. Create a bundle and put all the values in to bundle like:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("key",integervalue);
bundle.putString("key",string);
.......
```

After you put everything into bundle, pass it to fragment like:

```
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then in fragment use `getArguments()` to get the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Do like below

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("ValueName","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

Assign valueid to ValueName and your value to value